# How can I make a year in a SOQL query variable?

Tags: soql, query, date

So I can run a query such as

```
WHERE Date__c > 2020-07-31
```

but then next year "2020" would be out of date. I'd like "2020" to be variable so that next year, when I run this again, it will automatically be set to "2021".

So essentially I need my year to be variable and for it to always be equal to last year. It should be:

```
WHERE Date__c > [last year]-07-31
```

Is there any way to do this (without using Apex since this would be used in Conga)?

I saw that there's a LAST_YEAR function in SOQL but I can't write "LAST_YEAR-07-31" for some reason.

To clarify, my Date__c field is of type Date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following [Date Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm):

- `CALENDAR_MONTH`
- `CALENDAR_YEAR`
- `DAY_IN_MONTH`

Which in combination would look like:

```
WHERE CALENDAR_YEAR(Date__c) = 2021
AND CALENDAR_MONTH(Date__c) = 7
AND DAY_IN_MONTH(Date__c) = 31
```

If you want it to be always a specific date last year, you need a [Date Literal](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) as well. That would change your query filter to:

```
WHERE Date__c = LAST_YEAR
AND CALENDAR_MONTH(Date__c) = 7
AND DAY_IN_MONTH(Date__c) = 31
```

---

I misread the `>` as `=`, the above can be simplified to:

```
WHERE Date__c = LAST_YEAR
AND CALENDAR_MONTH(Date__c) > 7
```

Comment: Thank you! So my current criteria are "WHERE Date__c > 2020-07-30 AND Date__c < 2021-07-31". How could I make the year part of both criteria variable in this scenario?

Comment: Basically it should always be "greater than [last year]-07-30 and lesser than [this year]-07-31" but I'm not quite sure how to get there.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out within a specific fiscal year or?

Answer (score 3):

you can use [SOQL Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm): with a combination of date functions.
For your current example:

```
WHERE Date__c = LAST_YEAR
AND CALENDAR_MONTH(Date__c) >= 8
```